# How to explicitly delete an AES key generated in .NET using AESManaged?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I am experimenting with generating and deleting AES keys in `.NET`. This is just a self learning exercise and not going to be deployed anywhere. The following code generates an AES key using `AESManaged`

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace genkeys
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("generating keys with .NET");

                AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
                aes.GenerateKey();
                aes.GenerateIV();
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                Console.ReadLine(); 
                // how to delete the generated key here?

        }
    }
}
```

Theoretically, I understand that proper key hygiene dictates that we remove the keys immediately from RAM after we are done. In `C++`, the explicit call to `CryptDestroyKey` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdestroykey) allows us to wipe the keys. Is there an equivalent call in `.NET`. In other words, how do I delete the generated key in the code above? (I tried `cngkey.Delete()` but it did not work in this context).

Answer (score 1):

You would use `aes.Clear();`

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: thank you. I tried it but it seems that the key _still_ lingers in memory after an `aes.Clear`!

Comment: Well, otherwise, from my understanding of **AES** in **C#**, you **can't.**

Comment: I'll research some more, and get back to you in a couple of minutes.

Comment: You can set `aes` to `null`, then spit some random values into it, then call `GC.Collect()`

Comment: @Momoro Will `GC.Collect()` actually flush these resources, or just push them into the next generation?

Comment: @John , yes, it **should.**

Comment: Then am I correct in understanding that no explicit API call exists that is the equivalent of `CryptDestroyKey` in `.NET`? (`AES.Clear()` definitely did not clear the key. I checked in the debugger.)

Comment: @learnerX , **you are correct.** (Otherwise from `AES.Clear()`, you **can't** clear the key.)

Comment: `AesManaged` is `IDisposable`, `using` it should clear the key? (https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/AesManaged.cs)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I put the code above in a loop with `aes.Clear()` within the loop. And yet, in two iterations of the loop, I can find _both_ keys. One I see at `2DF94B18D50` and the other at `2DFAEE78050` (lingering from the previous iteration).

Comment: It's possible for the garbage collector to move the array before it is cleared.